# Array in for loop returning one value

Tags: php, arrays

i made a function in which i want all data from database and it is in for loop but still i am getting only one value and also the word 'array' being printed on top of my page

```
function example($requirement)
{
   global $wpdb;
   $data = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_arete_woocommerce_checkout_region_states");
   $results="";
   $state_results="";
   $country_results="";
   if($requirement=="front")
   {

      if (count ($data) > 0) {
         foreach ( $data as $result ) { 

           $country_results=$result->country_code;
           $state_results[''.$result->state_code.'']= ''.$result->state.'';

           $results[$country_results] = $state_results;
        }  
      }
    }

   return $results; 

}
```

output

```
ArrayArray
(
    [IN] =&gt; Array
        (
            [HR] =&gt; haryana
        )

)
```

Comment: $results is an array so if you want to print you can use print_r to view array structure, or a foreach( ), for the value returned by this function

Comment: Are you using `echo` or `print` to print the results array? Because that would result in `Array` being printed.

Comment: I am using echo later on to output the result . But it seems to get only one result but there is more results in database .

Comment: Use print_r to print the array

Comment: I have added the output

Comment: define  $results=array();

Comment: @VishalJ thank you for your reply . I have already tried that . No use